# Rendering specific component using switch case --- React

Tags: reactjs

My requirement is to render components based on user selection. 
I have a left nav on click of which I am trying to render the component associated with it but I am getting error:

Error:

Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

My code goes as under:

------ManageData.js-------

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import NestedList from '../Left-nav/leftnav';
import '../Left-nav/leftnav.css';
import AddCarousel from '../addCarousel/addCarousel';
import AddClass from '../addClass/addClass';
import './manageData.css';

class ManageData extends Component {
    loadComponent = null;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showChild: 1
        };
        //this.generateComponent = this.generateComponent.bind(this);
    }

    loadComponents = (data) => {
        console.log(data, this.state);
        if (data == 'AddClass') {
            this.setState({
                showChild: 2
            }, () => {

                console.log('state changed-----', this.state)
                //this.generateComponent(data, this.state);
            })
        }

    }




    render() {
        const showItem = this.state.showChild;


        return (

            <section className = "Admin-add-video">
            <div className="row">

            <div className = "col-3 set-padding" > < NestedList loadComponents = {this.loadComponents}/>
            </div >
            <div className = "col-9 set-ht" >
             { this.state.showChild == 1 && <AddCarousel/> }
              {this.state.showChild == 2 && <AddClass/>}

            </div>


            </div>
            </section>

        );
    }
}


export default ManageData;
```

Nested List is the separate component on click of its item I am getting the value and trying to setState().

I have tried everything from this url : [using switch statement for react rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784166/using-switch-statement-for-react-rendering) 
But for all the cases I am getting same error.

May be I am missing anything. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: ScreenShot]

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Are `AddCarousel` and `AddClass` React components?

Comment: @DineshPandiyan Yes

Comment: It looks like the problem is with `AddClass` component. Pl double check it is exported correctly.

Comment: share component code as well.

Comment: @Dinesh you were right I was not exporting the component properly.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm posting my comment as answer. Pl mark it as accepted answer so it will help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with `AddClass` component. Pl double check if it is exported correctly.

*Note: Posting this answer from my comment on the question as it fixed OP's error.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the render method:

```
render() {
        const { showChild } = this.state;

        const renderChilds = () => {
            switch(showChild) {
                case 1:
                    return <AddCarousel />;
                case 2:
                    return <AddClass />;
                default:
                    return <div />;
            }
        };

        return (
            <section className="Admin-add-video">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className = "col-3 set-padding">
                        < NestedList loadComponents={this.loadComponents} />
                    </div >
                    <div className = "col-9 set-ht" >
                        {renderChilds()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
```